# Proper way to cleanup dynamic engines and can they be loaded twice?

Tags: m2crypto

I am having problems loading Engine PKCS #11 as a dynamic engine using python and M2Crypto.  I am trying to access an Aladdin USB eToken.

Here are the important steps from my python code:

```
dynamic = Engine.load_dynamic_engine("pkcs11", "/usr/local/ssl/lib/engines/engine_pkcs11.so")
pkcs11 = Engine.Engine("pkcs11")
pkcs11.ctrl_cmd_string("MODULE_PATH", "/usr/lib/libeTPkcs11.so")
pkcs11.engine_init_custom()  # initialize engine with custom M2Crypto patch
# next few steps which I deleted pass password and grab key & cert off token    
Engine.cleanup()
```

This works fine the first time this method gets run.  The second time, it fails when loading the dynamic engine (see error below).

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in ?
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/M2Crypto/Engine.py", line 98, in load_dynamic_engine
    e.ctrl_cmd_string("LOAD", None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/M2Crypto/Engine.py", line 38, in ctrl_cmd_string
    raise EngineError(Err.get_error())
M2Crypto.Engine.EngineError: 4002:error:260B606D:engine routines:DYNAMIC_LOAD:init failed:eng_dyn.c:521:

Is it impossible to load engines twice in a python session?  Am I missing some kind of engine cleanup/deletion?  The OpenSSL docs talk about engine_finish() but I don't think M2Crypto offers that.  Is there a method to tell if the engine is already loaded?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like M2Crypto needs to be patched to have ENGINE_finish() and ENGINE_free() available.

Answer (score 0):

[M2Crypto](http://chandlerproject.org/Projects/MeTooCrypto) does have ENGINE_finish and ENGINE_free available in the svn trunk version. The `Engine` class has `init`, and `finish` methods, and when an instance gets deleted it will be `free`'d. Can you give that a try? If you see any issues there is still time to fix them for next release.

Comment: I finally got around to trying the latest M2Crypto.  I am using revision 723 from the repository.  I am using the init and finish methods which are new in M2Crypto.  The finish method throws a segmentation fault. (I'll post my code in a separate comment otherwise I'll run out of space)

As soon as the pkcs11.finish() line is hit, my script crashes with a segmentation fault.  The same thing was happening when I tried to patch M2Crypto myself and add a finish method.

Comment: Below is the code I am using:

    dynamic = Engine.load_dynamic_engine("pkcs11", "/usr/local/ssl/lib/engines/engine_pkcs11.so")
    pkcs11 = Engine.Engine("pkcs11")
    pkcs11.ctrl_cmd_string("MODULE_PATH", "/usr/lib/libeTPkcs11.so")
    pkcs11.init()  
    # next few steps which I deleted pass password and grab key & cert off token 
    pkcs11.finish()   
    Engine.cleanup()

Comment: Heikki - I am really stuck on this.  I don't know how to troubleshoot the segmentation fault.  Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

My python code displayed nicer than it is in the comment section.  The pkcs11.finish() method causes a segmentation fault in M2Crypto revision 723.

```
dynamic = Engine.load_dynamic_engine("pkcs11", "/usr/local/ssl/lib/engines/engine_pkcs11.so")
pkcs11 = Engine.Engine("pkcs11")
pkcs11.ctrl_cmd_string("MODULE_PATH", "/usr/lib/libeTPkcs11.so")
pkcs11.init()
# next few steps which I deleted pass password and grab key & cert off token
pkcs11.finish()                                   
Engine.cleanup()
```

Anyone have advice on whether I'm doing something wrong or if there is a problem with the M2Crypto code?